# Should including an external webpage in PHP be dangerous in principle?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
    include("https://example.com");
?>
```

I came across the opinion that including webpages in such pattern can be dangerous; further more, in XAMPP for windows php.ini there is `allow_url_include=Off` ; perhaps because some HTML files may include malicious JavaScript.

Comment: `include()` on a remote server do not work the same as `include()` on the local system. A local include takes the actual code and is basically added to your code. A remote include actually takes the **output** of the code and then adds the results to your code.

Comment: What is your relationship to the external webpage server? And also why are you talking about JS in the context of a PHP server-side include directive?

Comment: @CBHacking I don't understand your first question, it's just an example, but in actuality I just want to present codes from my GitHub profile in my personal website (without copy-pasting and cross-maintenance) ; PHP-including a file with unknown JavaScript could be dangerous **in principle**.

Comment: @Semo If you maintain control over the security of your GitHub profile and commit permissions on the repository in question, that's fine. If the repository is compromised, your server also gets compromised. I recommend at least having 2FA enabled on GitHub.

Comment: @Semo As an aside, `allow_url_include=Off` has nothing to do with HTML or JavaScript. It's a security option designed to prevent PHP include & require statements from referencing URLs in the way you're doing here. It protects against remote file inclusion (RFI) vulnerabilities where an attacker may be able to influence the include path, e.g. `include($_GET['page'] . '.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including external pages is just as dangerous as executing any other code sourced from the Internet (because that's exactly what you're doing). If you trust the source of the file - either because you own the server, or (with high confidence) control the content the owner displays there and also trust the security of the server/site - then this is fine; it's basically a more-direct alternative to first retrieving the file to your server (from the remote server), and then including the retrieved file using a local path.

On the other hand, the retrieved webpage will be parsed like any other included file. This means that, if it contains PHP directives, they will execute on your server, in the context of your PHP process. A malicious included file can completely take over the PHP server process, access any data it can access, start arbitrary processes on your host, and so on. (It *can* also simply contain malicious client-side content that will be sent to the user's browser, but this is strictly dominated, risk-wise, by server compromise.) Thus the absolute requirement that you control, or at least fully trust, the source of the content you include (you also should indeed retrieve it via HTTPS, so that it can't be spoofed or modified en route).

If the included content is *not* malicious, it could still cause problems for you, but only in the same ways any other included content could. These include - but are not limited to - the following:

- Contain syntax errors, either in HTML, PHP, or (inline) JS. PHP syntax errors will causes a server-side error, everything else will just cause the browser to have trouble correctly displaying the resulting page.
- Conflict with server-side directives you have set. For example, if you intend to serve HTML but the included page tries to serve JSON, and the included page is included before any content is emitted, it can set arbitrary headers such as content-type, which might make the rest of your page be handled incorrectly by the browser.
- Conflict with client-side script due to scope collisions. For example, if your included page has inline Javascript like `let foo = 5`, and the rest of your page also contains something like `let foo = {}`, that will cause a client-side error due to the same page (from the browser's perspective) trying to define `window.foo` twice.
- Introduce vulnerabilities into your server or web application. For example, perhaps the included page reads URL parameters and echoes them, un-escaped, into the response. This is a classic reflected cross-site scripting vulnerability, which maybe [the rest of] your own code isn't vulnerable to but the included code is. Any other webapp vulns - including server-side ones like SQL injection or remote code execution - could also be introduced this way. Thus, you must trust the included code to not only be non-malicious, but also to actually be secure.

Again, that all is not a comprehensive list of risks, merely intended to give you an idea of possible risks. Furthermore, including remote content does have one additional risk: retrieval failure. What happens if your server tries to fetch the supplied URL, and the remote server is down, or responds with a 404, or hangs on the request for a long time before responding, or otherwise fails to act as expected? You can test for a successful `include` operation by examining its return code (by default it's `1` for success and `FALSE` for failure but the success value can also be set by an actual return statement in the included file if it contains a PHP directive). In either case, though, your server needs to cope with the include potentially failing.

I recommend reading the actual docs on this PHP feature: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to display HTML and JavaScript content from a remote source. You should **not** use `require()` or `include()` for this. These functions parse the source file as a PHP script, which means the code in there can execute PHP functions. If you're just showing HTML content, there's no reason to use these high-risk functions.

If the remote content is coming GitHub, then by using `include()` you're essentially giving anyone who can push commits to your GitHub repository complete control over your server. This means that if someone compromises your GitHub account (or just the repository) then they also compromise your server.

If you're just displaying HTML from the repository, there's no need for it to go through `include()` or `require()` at all. You can leave `allow_url_include` switched off in PHP.ini

Instead, use the [CURL API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to fetch the remote file, then echo its contents out. You could also use [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead, but it will not work for a URL if [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled in PHP.ini for security.